# protobuf python can't find include

Tags: python, c++, linux, python-2.7, protocol-buffers

I've noticed a few others having problems, and only solution I saw consisted of `CXXFLAGS` and `LDFLAGS`, yet those don't seem to work.

Trying to compile C++ protobuff for alternative Python version I compiled and installed on CentOS with virtualenv and on a user account:

```
$ cd ~/myApp
$ /opt/python-2.7/bin/virtualenv python
$ source ~/myApp/python/bin/activate
(python)$ cd ~/src/protobuf-2.5.0
(python)$ ./configure --prefix=$HOME/usr
(python)$ make && make install
```

Up pops a message saying:

> ---
>
> Libraries have been installed in:
>      /home/myuser/usr/lib
>
> If you ever happen to want to link against installed libraries
>   in a given directory, LIBDIR, you must either use libtool, and
>   specify the full pathname of the library, or use the `-LLIBDIR'
>   flag during linking and do at least one of the following:
>      - add LIBDIR to the`LD_LIBRARY_PATH' environment variable
>        during execution
>      - add LIBDIR to the `LD_RUN_PATH' environment variable
>        during linking
>      - use the`-Wl,-rpath -Wl,LIBDIR' linker flag
>      - have your system administrator add LIBDIR to `/etc/ld.so.conf'

Ok, moving on:

```
(python)$ export PROTOCOL_BUFFERS_PYTHON_IMPLEMENTATION=cpp
(python)$ export CXXFLAGS=-I$HOME/usr/include
(python)$ export LDFLAGS=-L$HOME/usr/lib
(python)$ cd python
(python)$ python setup.py build
```

And it drops out with:

```
Using EXPERIMENTAL C++ Implmenetation.
running build
running build_py
running build_ext
building 'google.protobuf.internal._net_proto2___python' extension
gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -g -O2 -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -I. -I/opt/python-2.7/include/python2.7 -c google/protobuf/pyext/python_descriptor.cc -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/google/protobuf/pyext/python_descriptor.o
cc1plus: warning: command line option "-Wstrict-prototypes" is valid for Ada/C/ObjC but not for C++
In file included from google/protobuf/pyext/python_descriptor.cc:36:
./google/protobuf/pyext/python_descriptor.h:39:40: error: google/protobuf/descriptor.h: No such file or directory
google/protobuf/pyext/python_descriptor.cc:37:43: error: google/protobuf/descriptor.pb.h: No such file or directory
In file included from google/protobuf/pyext/python_descriptor.cc:36:
./google/protobuf/pyext/python_descriptor.h:55: error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of ‘FieldDescriptor’ with no type
./google/protobuf/pyext/python_descriptor.h:55: error: invalid use of ‘::’
./google/protobuf/pyext/python_descriptor.h:55: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘*’ token
./google/protobuf/pyext/python_descriptor.h:81: error: expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before ‘*’ token
google/protobuf/pyext/python_descriptor.cc:48: error: expected initializer before ‘*’ token
google/protobuf/pyext/python_descriptor.cc:93: warning: deprecated conversion from string constant to ‘char*’
google/protobuf/pyext/python_descriptor.cc:93: warning: deprecated conversion from string constant to ‘char*’
google/protobuf/pyext/python_descriptor.cc:93: warning: deprecated conversion from string constant to ‘char*’
google/protobuf/pyext/python_descriptor.cc:93: warning: deprecated conversion from string constant to ‘char*’
google/protobuf/pyext/python_descriptor.cc:93: warning: deprecated conversion from string constant to ‘char*’
google/protobuf/pyext/python_descriptor.cc:152: error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of ‘DescriptorPool’ with no type
google/protobuf/pyext/python_descriptor.cc:152: error: invalid use of ‘::’
google/protobuf/pyext/python_descriptor.cc:152: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘*’ token
google/protobuf/pyext/python_descriptor.cc:158: error: expected unqualified-id before ‘*’ token
google/protobuf/pyext/python_descriptor.cc:158: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘*’ token
google/protobuf/pyext/python_descriptor.cc:158: error: expected initializer before ‘*’ token
google/protobuf/pyext/python_descriptor.cc:337: error: expected ‘}’ at end of input
google/protobuf/pyext/python_descriptor.cc:337: error: expected ‘}’ at end of input
google/protobuf/pyext/python_descriptor.cc:337: error: expected ‘}’ at end of input
google/protobuf/pyext/python_descriptor.cc:155: warning: ‘void google::protobuf::python::CDescriptorPoolDealloc(google::protobuf::python::CDescriptorPool*)’ declared ‘static’ but never defined
error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

Comment: Where is `google/protobuf/descriptor.h`?

Comment: (python)$ cd ~/; find ./ -iname descriptor.h
./usr/include/google/protobuf/descriptor.h
./src/protobuf-2.5.0/src/google/protobuf/descriptor.h
(python)$

Comment: It would appear that setuptools is not paying attention to the `CXXFLAGS` environment variable -- you can see that your `CXXFLAGS` is not appearing in the gcc command line. It looks like it may not even be aware that it's compiling C++, considering that it's using `gcc` and not `g++`. Does `CFLAGS` work?

Comment: Thank you Kenton, that seems to work, though I still cannot get the testing ('python setup.py test') to work, the install at least seems to work; and from following through an example or two, that seems to work as well.

Will you place this as an answer so I can mark that as an accepted answer, and so that you can receive the appropriate credit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would appear that setuptools is not paying attention to the `CXXFLAGS` environment variable -- you can see that your `CXXFLAGS` is not appearing in the `gcc` command line. It looks like it may not even be aware that it's compiling C++, considering that it's using `gcc` and not `g++`. Try using `CFLAGS` instead.

Comment: The only outstanding question I have on this topic is why "python setup.py test" fails.  Other than that, your solution appears to work, thank you.

Comment: @PinBot Hard to say without logs. It could be because of `PROTOCOL_BUFFERS_PYTHON_IMPLEMENTATION=cpp` -- that turns on an experimental implementation that has a few obscure issues.